# Difference between Linux Mint LXDE 11 RC(28 June) and Linux Mint 11 (released 28 May)

Tags: linux-mint

What is the difference between `Linux Mint LXDE 11 RC`(28 June) and `Linux Mint Katya 11` (released 26 May)? The release notes seems exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Linux Mint Katya 11" is the 11th release of the [Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/) distribution, code-named "Katya."

"Linux Mint LXDE 11 RC" is a Release Candidate of Mint 11 that uses the [LXDE](http://lxde.org/) desktop environment instead of [GNOME](http://gnome.org).

Comment: Thanks.  [LXDE]is especially designed for cloud computers with low hardware specifications, such as, netbooks, mobile devices (e.g. MIDs) or older computers. That means, I do not have to go for it as I am on 8 core/8GB laptop and need better graphics and just lightweight.

Answer (score 2):

RC stands for release candidate. It's sort of a pre-release version after the beta testing process is over to check for last minute bugs. Sometimes everything checks out and RC versions get turned into release versions as is, sometimes little things crop up and small fixes are made before the final release.

LXDE is a desktop environment, often packaged as an alternate version of some distros.